# How to display only numbers in a column if it has strings and numbers. if only string is present then the column should left as empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please help me to find a Sql query/ procedure for below request.

I am having column A which is having below values in each row

```
COLUMN A
My toy is in ('111000','1112220')
My toy is this
My toy is in ('111000')
My toy is this 
My toy is in ('111002')
```

Now i need a query to display the column A with value containing only numbers, If the row is not having any number then it should be left as empty like below

```
COLUMN A
111000|1112220

111000

111002
```

if it is a stored procedure/ a query any thing is fine for me. Please help me on this

Comment: is the bracketed part always at the end of the string?

Comment: @AlexK. No. The bracketed part can also be followed by any string.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

Use the function as

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(column_name) 
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Naively in the hope that this is a one off job to fix/normalize the data:

```
select
    replace(replace(substring(columnA, a + 1, b - a), '''', ''), ',', '|')
from (
    select 
        columnA,
        charindex('(''', columnA) a,
        charindex(''')', columnA) b
    from your_table
) t
```

- Assumes 1 set of `('')`